# BigQuery: How to unescape an extra-escaped/serialized JSON string

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I'm working with a dataset in which JSON-strings are being pulled from a service and have gone through an extra layer of string extraction/processing, such that the JSON syntax in the string itself has been escaped.

It's easier to show as an example — here's a CSV in which `body` is a JSON-formatted string:

```
id,body
1,"{""name"":""hello"",""value"":9}"
2,"{""value"":42}"
```

Here's what I'm working with:

```
id,body
1,"""{\""name\"":\""hello\"",\""value\"":9}"""
2,"""{\""value\"":42}"""
```

If I had to guess, it's as if the source service is pulling in the JSON-formatted string of `body`, as if it were expecting to be serialized as a string value within another JSON string.

Whatever the case, is there a straightforward way to unescape this string so that I can use JSON_EXTRACT, etc. as normal?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like the easy solution is to run `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` on the string, and then the `JSON_EXTRACT` operation I actually want to do, e.g.

```sql
SELECT 
  id
  , JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(body, '$'), '$.value') AS value
FROM 
  datatable
```